# Maven Java Home Path: \bin, or not to \bin

Tags: java, maven, path, java-home

So I find myself kind of stuck in between.

I set JAVA_HOME to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121` then Maven works but

```
java -version
```

shows `'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

If I set JAVA_HOME to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin`, Maven doesn't work but at least I get `java -version` right.

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something fundamentally wrong but I can't put my finger on it, obviously :(

Comment: `java -version` will look at your $PATH, so normally we need to add %JAVA_HOME%/bin to $PATH for any ad-hoc command. For maven, internally it checks $JAVA_HOME/bin. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Apolozeus Your comment solved my issue. Make it an answer, I will accept it as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java -version` will look at your $PATH, so normally we need to add %JAVA_HOME%/bin to $PATH for any ad-hoc command. For maven, internally it checks $JAVA_HOME/bin. Hope it helps.